# How do I build two selects on different columns?

Tags: sql, select

I´m trying to create a table with two different selects in two different columns. What SQL command can I use?

Obs: "NAME_FAB" means Name Manufacturer.

```
Expected result:
NAME_FAB            Y           X
manufacturer1      100.0      20.0
manufacturer2       80.0      10.0
manufacturer3      120.0       5.0
```

```
--COLUMN Y
SELECT PRODUCT.NAME_FAB, SUM(NFOUT_ITENS.TOTAL_VALUE) AS Y
FROM NFOUT
    INNER JOIN NFOUT_ITENS
    ON NFOUT_ITENS.IDOUT = NFOUT.COD
    INNER JOIN PRODUCT
    ON PRODUCT.COD = NFOUT_ITENS.IDPRODUCT
WHERE NFOUT.DT_EMIT BETWEEN '2019-07-01' AND '2019-07-31'
AND NFOUT.FINAL = 'NORMAL'
GROUP BY PRODUCT.NAME_FAB

**HERE**

--COLUMN X
SELECT PRODUCT.NAME_FAB, SUM(NFOUT_ITENS.TOTAL_VALUE) AS X
FROM NFOUT
    INNER JOIN NFOUT_ITENS
    ON NFOUT_ITENS.IDOUT = NFOUT.COD
    INNER JOIN PRODUCT
    ON PRODUCT.COD = NFOUT_ITENS.IDPRODUCT
WHERE NFOUT.DT_EMIT BETWEEN '2019-07-01' AND '2019-07-31'
AND NFOUT.FINAL = 'DEVOL'
GROUP BY PRODUCT.NAME_FAB
```

Comment: Edit your question and show your source data, an explanation of the logic, and a tag for the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT p.NAME_FAB,
       SUM(CASE WHEN o.FINAL = 'DEVOL' THEN i.TOTAL_VALUE END) AS X,
       SUM(CASE WHEN o.FINAL = 'NORMAL' THEN i.TOTAL_VALUE END) AS Y
FROM NFOUT o JOIN
     NFOUT_ITENS i
     ON i.IDOUT = s.COD JOIN
     PRODUCT p
     ON p.COD = i.IDPRODUCT
WHERE o.DT_EMIT BETWEEN '2019-07-01' AND '2019-07-31' 
GROUP BY p.NAME_FAB;
```

Your `FROM` clauses do not have `NFOUT` so I added it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the X and Y in the same column try the UNION and change the Y alias to X.

```
--COLUMN from NFSAIDA
SELECT PRODUCT.NAME_FAB, SUM(NFOUT_ITENS.TOTAL_VALUE) AS X
FROM NFSAIDA
    INNER JOIN NFOUT_ITENS
    ON NFOUT_ITENS.IDOUT = NFOUT.COD
    INNER JOIN PRODUCT
    ON PRODUCT.COD = NFOUT_ITENS.IDPRODUCT
WHERE NFOUT.DT_EMIT BETWEEN '2019-07-01' AND '2019-07-31'
AND NFOUT.FINAL = 'NORMAL'
GROUP BY PRODUCT.NAME_FAB

UNION

--COLUMN from NFOUT
SELECT PRODUCT.NAME_FAB, SUM(NFOUT_ITENS.TOTAL_VALUE) AS X
FROM NFOUT
    INNER JOIN NFOUT_ITENS
    ON NFOUT_ITENS.IDOUT = NFOUT.COD
    INNER JOIN PRODUCT
    ON PRODUCT.COD = NFOUT_ITENS.IDPRODUCT
WHERE NFOUT.DT_EMIT BETWEEN '2019-07-01' AND '2019-07-31'
AND NFOUT.FINAL = 'DEVOL'
GROUP BY PRODUCT.NAME_FAB
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use two cte's. I hope this works as I was not able to test. You may want to change the inner join on t1 and t2 to full outer join if your data is such:

```
WITH t1 AS
(
SELECT PRODUCT.NAME_FAB, SUM(NFOUT_ITENS.TOTAL_VALUE) AS Y
FROM NFOUT
    INNER JOIN NFOUT_ITENS
    ON NFOUT_ITENS.IDOUT = NFOUT.COD
    INNER JOIN PRODUCT
    ON PRODUCT.COD = NFOUT_ITENS.IDPRODUCT
WHERE NFOUT.DT_EMIT BETWEEN '2019-07-01' AND '2019-07-31'
AND NFOUT.FINAL = 'NORMAL'
GROUP BY PRODUCT.NAME_FAB
),
t2 AS
(
SELECT PRODUCT.NAME_FAB, SUM(NFOUT_ITENS.TOTAL_VALUE) AS X
FROM NFOUT
    INNER JOIN NFOUT_ITENS
    ON NFOUT_ITENS.IDOUT = NFOUT.COD
    INNER JOIN PRODUCT
    ON PRODUCT.COD = NFOUT_ITENS.IDPRODUCT
WHERE NFOUT.DT_EMIT BETWEEN '2019-07-01' AND '2019-07-31'
AND NFOUT.FINAL = 'DEVOL'
GROUP BY PRODUCT.NAME_FAB
)
SELECT t1.NAME_FAB, t1.Y, t2.X
FROM t1
INNER JOIN t2 ON t1.NAME_FAB = t2.NAME_FAB
```